# Flux toIterable not lazy as it stated in the doc

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor, iterable

I'm working on a school project using Reactor and am running into some issues with `Flux`.

On the upstream, I have a `Flux` that is reading from database and generating rows for the downstream processor to use. For example:

```
public Flux<Row> emitRow(...) 
{ 
  return Flux.create(cursor -> {
     ... logic to read and check db ...
     emitRow(cursor, row);
     cursor.complete()
  });
}
```

Reading everything into memory is not ideal since our sandbox environment has a limited amount of memory. So, what I have setup is every time we read a row, we process it before getting the next row.

Initially, I have something like this setup and it seems to work, however, my instructor said we need to use `toIterable()` instead.

```
public Mono<Outcome> process(Flux<Row> data)
{
    return data
        .flatMap(row -> processRow(row), SINGLE_THREAD, SINGLE_THREAD)
        .map(results -> new Outcome(results));
}
```

So right now, I'm trying to make it work with `toIterable()` but having trouble. That is what I have in mind, but it is not behaving as stated in the JavaDoc. It looks like with this, there are 2 queues involved. First one is the iterable iterator's blocking queue and the second is from the original `Flux.create`. And the second queue (from `Flux.create`) seems to be buffering everything into memory causing out of memory exception in my application.

```
public Mono<Outcome> process(Flux<Row> data)
{
    Iterator<Row> itr = data.toIterable(1).iterator();
    return Mono.fromCallable(() -> processRow(itr))
            .map(results -> new Outcome(results));
}

public Results processRow(Iterator<Row> itr) 
{
   while(itr.hasNext())  <--- This is suppose to be blocking
   {
      Row r = itr.next();
      dbContentBuilder.handle(r);
   }
   return new Results(dbContentBuilder.build());
}
```

Any idea why or how to make it work with iterable so that Flux.create does not try to buffer everything into the sync, and instead iterator.next() will ask for the next chunk.
The documentation seems to suggest that this is a lazy queue and will block when ask for the `.next()`. Doc: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#toIterable-int-

Comment: I've removed your side-question. Questions on SO should focus on one thing.

Comment: Edit your answer including the implementation of `processRow(itr)`.

Comment: Added relevant implementation of processRow

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you've understood your instructor correctly? Using iterable in this case makes no sense, especially if you're trying to return a publisher (which you definitely shouldn't do when it's trying to wrap blocking code.)

Comment: Yes, that's what the instructor asked. I checked with him again today.

Comment: I think maybe there is some sort of back pressure configuration I can set?